# Recycle Bitmap in android

Tags: android, bitmap

First, I use `AsyncTask` to download bitmap and contain bitmap into array.

`myBitmap[0] = task.execute().get();`

My first question is, if I `recycle()` my array of `Bitmap` and download by using

`ASyncTask` again when start `Activity`, This would cause any problems to memory or not.

Because if I download all `Bitmap` into my device, errors would occur surely. That's why I

have to download and remove them again and again.

And second question is, If I have some `Bitmap` as follows:

`Bitmap newBitmap = myBitmap[0];`

Do I have to `recycle()` the `newBitmap` to decrease memory?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I think you will have to call recycle to decrease memory usage. You could do it 
1. when overwriting an existing bitmap location
2. releasing all bitmaps when exiting the app
3. Keeping tabs on number of bitmaps loaded at one time.

I suggest using an LruCache to manage the bitmaps. Helpful when keeping tabs on which bitmap is used most frequently etc.